# Find the equivalence class of a cartesian product.

Tags: linear-algebra, relations, equivalence-relations

This is the question:

Let $R$ be a relation on cartesian product $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ where $(x,y)\mathrel R(u,v)$ iff $xv = yu$. Find the equivalence class $[(3,5)]$.

*This is what i tried:*

---

$[(3,5)]$ $=$ {$(u,v) \in N: (3,5)\mathrel R(u,v)$}

$=$ {$(u,v)\in N:3v=5u$}

$=${$(u,v)\in N:u=\frac 53 \times v$}

$=${$(5,2);(10,6);(15,9);...$}

---

But I am unsure if this is correct or not, could someone please check if it makes sense, thanks.

Comment: $3v = 5u$  means $\frac{3}{5} v = u $   or, same thing $\frac{5}{3} u = v.$   The thing you expect  before checking is  reflexivity, we expect to have $(3,5)  R (3,5)$  Check!

Comment: The beginning is fine but your last line is wrong. Hint: since $3$ and $5$ are coprime, $3v=5u\implies3\mid u.$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining equivalence class of relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2516589/determining-equivalence-class-of-relations)

Comment: Yes, finally got it. Thanks